# Obtener valores php

Tags: php, post, get

Necesito obtener valores en php, el problema es que desconozco el nombre de las variables que se envian hay alguna forma de obtener el nombre o las variables con php?
el codigo es el siguiente

```
$deviceID = $_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICEID'];

$rawPostData = "DeviceID: ".$deviceID."\n";
$rawPostData .= print_r($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'], TRUE);

$filedatetime=date('ymdHis');
$rawPostFile = "data/playlog_".$filedatetime.".txt";
$rawPostHandler = fopen($rawPostFile, 'w') or die('Could not open file!');
fwrite($rawPostHandler, $rawPostData) or die('Could not write to file');
fclose($rawPostHandler);

$fileStream .= $rawPostData;
```

al querer obtener datos con global ya no los recibe, al parecer ya no se envian con ese nombre, pero no tengo forma de saber como se envian
de antemano gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Si el fragmento de código que estás usando será imposible darte una respuesta. Puedes [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/114118/edit)  para colocar tu código y de paso indicar si ves algún mensaje de error.

Comment: ya anexe mi codigo, pero la pregunta sigue siendo hay manera de obtener datos sin saber el nombre?

Comment: ¿Cuáles son las variables cuyos valores quieres conocer? ¿Desde dónde, desde una URL?

Comment: estoy usando un brightsign, el cual lo configure para que envie los logs, el problema es que desconozco con que variables se envia, con el codigo anterior estoy tratando de obtener algunos datos, hay forma de saber que otras variables estoy recibiendo? creo que no me estoy explicando bien

Comment: ya quedo, muchisimas gracias por responder, solo cambie HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código tiene algunos problemas.

Vamos a enumerarlos:

**1. Uso indebido de `print_r`**

`print_r` no sirve para almacenar valores en variables, sino para imprimir valores ya almacenados.

Por lo tanto este código es incorrecto:

<s>`$rawPostData .= print_r($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'], TRUE);`</s>

**2. `HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` es obsoleto**

Según el [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php):

> `HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` Esta característica fue declarada OBSOLETA en
>   PHP 5.6.0 y ELILMINADA a partir de PHP 7.0.0.

Por lo tanto, si estás usando PHP 7, no obtendrás nada con esto:

<s>`$rawPostData .= print_r($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'], TRUE);`</s>

`HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` ha sido reemplazado por `php://input` [como dice el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/wrappers.php.php):

> `php://input` es un flujo de sólo lectura que permite leer datos del
>   cuerpo solicitado. En el caso de peticiones POST, es preferible usar
>   `php://input` en vez de `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` ya que no depende de
>   directivas php.ini especiales. Sin embargo, cuando no se genera
>   automáticamente `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`, se trata de una alternativa que
>   hace un uso menos intensivo de memoria que activando
>   `always_populate_raw_post_data`. `php://input` no está disponible con
>   `enctype="multipart/form-data`.

**3. El caso de `HTTP_DEVICEID` no aparece documentación sobre él**

Evidentemente tratas de obtener el id del dispositivo. No encontré datos sobre eso. En SO en inglés sugieren leer los datos del User-Agent para obtenerlo o usar librerías de terceros.

---

Vamos a aplicar las correcciones mencionadas:

```
//$deviceID = $_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICEID']; 

//$rawPostData = "DeviceID: ".$deviceID."\n";  ver como obtenerlo
$rawPostData = file_get_contents("php://input");

/*Aquí puedes revisar lo que hay en $rawPostData con print_r*/
print_r($rawPostData);

$filedatetime=date('ymdHis');
$rawPostFile = "data/playlog_".$filedatetime.".txt";
$rawPostHandler = fopen($rawPostFile, 'w') or die('Could not open file!');
fwrite($rawPostHandler, $rawPostData) or die('Could not write to file');
fclose($rawPostHandler);

$fileStream .= $rawPostData;
```

Comment: muchas gracias, algunas variables no se muestran declaradas por que no agregue la parte de arriba que es donde las declaro para no hacer tan largo el codigo , y en efecto el problema estaba en raw_post, que como mencionas esta obsoleto, remplace esa parte y esta funcionando.

Comment: Me alegro @IsaiLopez borraré el punto 3 de la respuesta. Saludos.